# MySQL Query select concat on json field ids

Tags: mysql, json, join, concatenation

i have this two tables

**Table 1: "Identity"**

```
ID | identifier | report_ids
------------------------------
1  | TOP        | ["1","2"]
```

***The "report_ids" is a VARCHAR column, not JSON***

**Table 2: "Reports"**

```
ID | name
------------------------------
1  | Report Food
2  | Report Beverage
```

I have to select from table Identity and Join the table Reports to get the names by his ids

in summary, i hope to have this result with a query:

```
Result:
ID | identifier | report_names
--------------------------------
1  | TOP        | Report Food, Report Beverage
```

How i can do this with Query?

Thanks in advance at all :)

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? *The "report_ids" is a VARCHAR column, not JSON* It doesn't matter - if it is valid JSON then it can be used as an argument in JSON functions.

Comment: My version is: 10.4.10-MariaDB, i have the varchar because not all time this value is json, but i think it could be casted to json no?

Comment: If so you must show "values which are not JSON" and tell what output do you need for such rows. Or maybe you need to process only those rows which contains valid JSON values?

Comment: the second, i need to process only those rows which contains valid JSON values

Comment: Anycase - MariaDB does not implement JSON_TABLE function or similar - so you need in iterative CTE which will extract separate values from your JSON, then join 2nd table and use GROUP_CONCAT to reconstruct single CSV value which you need. Alternatively you may quote reports.id with `"` and search for it in identity.reprots_id.

Comment: what you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for

```
SELECT i.id, i.identifier, GROUP_CONCAT(r.name)
FROM Identity i
JOIN Reports r ON LOCATE(CONCAT('"', r.id, '"'), i.report_ids)
GROUP BY i.id, i.identifier
-- WHERE JSON_VALID(i.report_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is great. However, to complete, and since this question is tagged as 'mysql', I would like to add the solution with **MySQL 8.0** (since this was very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65669023/mysql-join-in-a-json-array/65862080#65862080)).

As mentioned in the comments, `JSON_TABLE` can be used, and with `JSON_ARRAYAGG` you can directly proced JSON in the result:

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.identifier, JSON_ARRAYAGG(reports.name)
FROM identity as i
    JOIN JSON_TABLE(i.report_ids, '$[*]' COLUMNS (id INT PATH '$')) AS r 
    JOIN reports ON reports.id = r.id
GROUP BY i.id, i.id, i.identifier;
```

Result (was not sure which ID was wanted):

```
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
| id | identifier | JSON_ARRAYAGG(reports.name)        |
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | TOP        | ["Report food", "Report Beverage"] |
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
```