# MySQL join in a JSON array

Tags: mysql, json

I have these rows in mysql table

```
id  categoryNameSp    categoryNameEn
1   Comida            Food
2   Fruta             Fruit
3   Fruta Seca        Dried fruit
```

And then i have this row in another table

```
pid  path
1    ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I want to return the path but instead of numbers i want to return categoryNameEn so the return will be:

```
  pid  path
  1    ["Food","Fruit", "Dried fruit"]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to store the paths in a JSON array, if you wanted to do queries like this that treat the array elements as discrete values?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the goal was to allow a category search that would consider all selected categories just like a windows folder system would. So client side i store all the selected categories and then return the fruit with mysql function json_contains().

Comment: But why not store each path value on its own row? Then it would be a lot easier to do the join to the category table, without using complex JSON functions.

Comment: By doing so I would have been forced to determine the number of columns and therefore I would have had to determine a maximum number of subcategories but with the json I manage everything on the client side and I can manage it if I detect that the path is over

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would require to use the [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) functionality as well as the [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) aggregation function.

Recreating your situation using the following [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) and [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language):

```sql
CREATE TABLE categories (id INT, name VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO categories VALUES (1, 'Food'), (2, 'Fruit'), (3, 'Dried Fruit');

CREATE TABLE stuff (pid INT, path JSON);
INSERT INTO stuff VALUES (1, '["1", "2", "3"]');
```

Then we can do the following (fancy) query:

```sql
SELECT pid, JSON_ARRAYAGG(c.name) FROM stuff AS s
    JOIN JSON_TABLE(s.path, '$[*]' COLUMNS (category INT PATH '$')) AS cats
    JOIN categories AS c ON cats.category = c.id
    GROUP BY pid;
```

The idea is to create a table from the JSON data found in the `stuff` table. We then join it with the categories tables, and aggregate the result into a JSON array.

The result:

```
+------+----------------------------------+
| pid  | JSON_ARRAYAGG(c.name)            |
+------+----------------------------------+
|    1 | ["Food", "Fruit", "Dried Fruit"] |
+------+----------------------------------+
```